# 6DoF input for MeshLab?

Tags: meshlab

Anybody using a 3DConnexion (spaceball, spacemouse, etc.) or similar 6DoF input device for camera movement within MeshLab?
I'd like to see support for 6DoF HID devices, or at least figure how to fake it with the 3DConnexion configuration .xml.
Who's a 3dConnexion guru here?

Meshlab 2016.12 on win7pro
3DxWare 10.5.11
SpaceMousePro FW:4.35
I'm not a programmer, so don't know where to find the navigation hooks into meshlab.
I know 3DxWare can emulate joystick, panning, etc....
Unfortunately, 3DxConnexion won't publish their config file description.

Example of the config .xml the driver generates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppCfg Default="false" xmlns="" CfgFormatVersion="1.2" ThisFileVersion="1.10">
  <AppInfo>
    <Signature>
      <Name>meshlab</Name>
      <ExecutableName>meshlab.exe</ExecutableName>
    </Signature>
    <Options />
  </AppInfo>
  <CfgProperties>
    <InheritsFrom>STR_DEFAULT_KMJ</InheritsFrom>
  </CfgProperties>
  <Settings />
  <Devices>
    <Device>
      <Name>Standard 3D Mouse</Name>
      <VendorID>0</VendorID>
      <ProductID>0</ProductID>
      <InheritsFrom>Standard 3D Mouse</InheritsFrom>
      <AxisBank>
        <Name>Default</Name>
        <ID>Default</ID>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_X</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_X</ActionID>
            <Reversed>false</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Y</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Z</ActionID>
            <Reversed>false</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Z</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Y</ActionID>
            <Reversed>true</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Rx</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Rx</ActionID>
            <Reversed>false</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Ry</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Rz</ActionID>
            <Reversed>false</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Input>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Rz</ActionID>
            <Min>-512</Min>
            <Max>511</Max>
          </Input>
          <Output>
            <ActionID>HIDMultiAxis_Ry</ActionID>
            <Reversed>true</Reversed>
          </Output>
        </Axis>
      </AxisBank>
    </Device>
  </Devices>
  <AuthorInfo>
    <DriverVersion>17.5.11.15451</DriverVersion>
    <LastChange>
      <Tool>3DxSmartUI.exe</Tool>
      <Version>1.2.18291.15447</Version>
      <Date>4/4/2019 11:03:52 PM UTC</Date>
      <User>av284c</User>
    </LastChange>
  </AuthorInfo>
</AppCfg>
```

Functional 6DoF controller in meshlab